# How to set fields for an object based the object circumstances, without relying on boolean flags?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

We have a huge object which sets one by one a lot of fields. However, we've come to a point where we set 3 flags in order to create it based on what we need, which break clean code rules. Basically it looks something like this:

```
method(boolean flag1, boolean flag2, boolean flag3){
    if (flag1){
        field1 = customValue1;
    }
    if (flag2){
        field2 = customValue2;
    }
    if (flag3){
        field3 = customValue3;
    }
```

How can I refactor this so it follows the standard (get rid of all the flags)?

Making a separate method for each case wouldn't be alright I think because I would have a LOT of code duplicates (this method has over 200 lines of code due to the number of fields and the way the business logic works in general). Then I thought of creating some sort of Supplier object for each possible case, but... just no. What are my options?

Comment: "this method has over 1000 lines of code due to the number of fields" There's your problem. Address that. You are trying to treat a symptom rather than the cause.

Comment: Objects.should not have a lot of fields nor should methods be that large.  And methods are used to alleviate code duplication, not cause it.   I would first rethink your design.

Comment: Changing 1000 to 200 does not alter my recommendation to rethink your design.

Comment: @WJS how can you say "objects should not have a lot of fields"? It's completly non-sense sentence. It is quite common to have huge Objects with tons of methods and settings params/fields inside them.

Comment: It's not nonsense.  And I'm not talking about simple local variables but those that would be initialized in a constructor. Large classes like that become cumbersome to use.  And what do you mean by "tons of methods?"

Comment: Can you just pass the collection of field values, and pass null for fields you want to ignore?

Comment: It’s hard to imagine a real life case for what you have posted. So the class has 2×n fields and a method with *n* boolean parameters to copy one half of the fields to the other half of the fields? And in which regard would splitting the method into *n* methods create code duplication? Each of your `if` statements has three lines a code, a dedicated method for each assignment would also have three lines of code. The caller wouldn’t have to pass 100 boolean parameters but only call those methods actually doing something (where the parameter was true), so it would also be simpler (and readable)

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I refactor this so it follows the standard (get rid of all the flags)?*

How many fields do you have?  Have you considered a builder approach?

```
class Foo (
   Foo setValue1(int v1) {
         valueV1 = v1;
         return this;
   }
   Foo setValue2(String v2) {
        valueV2 = v2;
        return this;
   }
   Foo setValue3(double v3) {
         valueV3 = v3;
         return this;
   }
```

Then you set the required fields in a chain.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setValue1(23).setValue2(4.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @WJS said, there might be a possibility to break your large object into smaller objects and make your design follow the single responsibility principle by making those objects more coherent. Look for sets of fields and methods that work together and encapsulate them in another class.

In any way, consider using the **builder pattern** to create a complex object. In the builder class, each set of fields that must be initialized (or set) together would wrap in a single setter method.

```
class ComplexObjectBuilder{
  private ComplexObject result;

  public ComplexObjectBuilder SetFieldGroup1(int field1, ...)
  {
    // set actual fields
    result.Field1 = field1;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Builder pattern allows you to construct an object step by step while providing a clean and fluent API.

```
public class YourObjectBuilder {

 private YourObject object = new YourObject();

 public YourObjectBuilder withField1(customValue1Type value) {
     object.setField1(value);
     return this;
 }

 public YourObjectBuilder withField2(customValue2Type value) {
     object.setField2(value);
     return this;
 }

 public YourObjectBuilder withField3(customValue3Type value) {
     object.setField3(value);
     return this;
 }

 // Add more methods for other fields as needed

 public YourObject build() {
    return object;
 }
}
```

This way, you can construct your object by chaining the necessary field-setting methods.

Answer (score -2):

I'm usually create Bitwised Flag variables.
Each Integer could contains up to 32 different "boolean" flags so if I need to declare 33 boolean values I create just 2 Integers inside this Class.

```
class MyClass {
    static final int FLAG_NONE = 0;
    static final int FLAG1_ENABLED = 1;
    static final int FLAG1_OPENED = 1 << 1;
    static final int FLAG1_HEAVY = 1 << 2;
    ...
    static final int FLAG1_FLYING = 1 << 31; //max value for a single Integer

    private int mFlags1 = 0;
    private int mFlags2 = 0;

    MyClass addFlags1(int flags) { mFlags |= flags; return this; }
    MyClass removeFlags1(int flags) { mFlags &= ~flags; }
    boolean hasFlags1(int flags) { return ((mFlags1 & flags) == flags); }
    ...do the same for "flags2"....
}
```

in this way you can set many flags together or sequencially:

```
final MyClass cNewClass = new MyClass();
cNewClass
    .addFlags1(FLAG1_ENABLED)
    .addFlags1(FLAG1_OPENED);
cNewClass.removeFlags1(FLAG1_HEAVY | FLAG1_FLYING);
if (cNewClass.hasFlags1(FLAG1_OPENED) || !cNewClass.hasFlags1(FLAG1_FLYING | FLAG1_ENABLED)) { ... }
```

Same resoult could be achived using ENUMS but I prefer simple Integer Bitwise values.

Comment: How does this solve the complexity issue? As a matter of fact, it brings more complexity to maintain those flags!

Comment: @R.Abbasi up to 64 boolean values can be set using bitwise (OR/AND) operators without the need of create a setter and getter methods for all of them.............so using only 6 methods is equal to have created 64 setters and 64 getters methods.

Comment: Is it human-readable? It's not always better to have less code. Maintaining those bitwise operations is hell.

Comment: @R.Abbasi Very human-readable if someone is not nOOb....Having methods in multiple of 3 methods instead of multiple of 96 (32 for getters, 32 for setters and 32 for check if the value is true) is still better than the other way. ALWAYS BETTER. Bitwise operations are managed by those 3 methods, so there isn't any "hell": when someone wants to set a Boolean to TRUE it requires just a method "addFlags(CONST_DOOR_OPENED)" similar to "setDoorStatus('opened')". Less code = better readability without all those getters/setters/checkers.

Comment: Not all developers on a project have the same skills or experience. So you should write it how even a nOOb can read it!

Comment: @R.Abbasi a "nOOB" in life, not in programming. It's quite easy to understand that it would be better to have LESS things (methods) beside A LOT OF THEM. Having 96 methods is ALWAYS the worst case in any case, in any language and for any programmer.